# How to set ssl certificate for a cname in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to aws and I am hosting a website in aws through cname(a.mysite.com) which will point to website(point.com). I had a certificate issued from aws for my a.mysite.com how can i attach that certificate to a.mysite.com to make that as https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install custom SSL certificate in DNS Level. In order for your endpoint to serve securely using SSL, you need to install those certificates in web server (vhost). You can refer to the below reference on how to install.

Apache2

https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/ubuntu-server-with-apache2-openssl.htm

Nginx

https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/nginx-openssl.htm